# Multiplying elements together inside a nested list after a specific index in python

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list and I'd like to multiply all the elements, after a certain index, inside the list with each other. Like for example if my list is like this, (where all the elements inside (a1,f,g etc) are variables)

```
A=[[a1,a2,a3,f, g, g ],[b1, b2,b3, d, g, d]]
```

Id like for all the nested elements the third element to be multiplied together.
So the output would be as a such,

```
A=[[a1,a2,a3,f*g**2], [b1, b2, b3, d**2*g]]
```

In addition, Im wondering if theres a way to separately multiply the remaining elements with the product at the end of each nested list,

```
A=[[a1*f*g**2,a2*f*g**2, a3*f*g**2], [b1*d**2*g, b2*d**2*g, b3*d**2*g]]
```

Im not really sure how to begin approaching this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you want i didn't understand.

Comment: how do you get `f*g**2` or `d**2*g` ? does that mean `g**2` == `g*g`?

Comment: What do you mean by multiplying strings together? Or are 'a1' 'a2' ect... meant to be numerical variables

Comment: Oh ok 1 second I'll edit is better. They arnt meant to be strings

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the question, you can use a list comprehension to iterate over the sublists of A, followed by list indexing and the reduce function to compute what is required

```
import functools

A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
B = [sublist[:3] + [functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, sublist[3:])] for sublist in A]

print(B)
```

For the second part its better to do this with an explicit for loop so that the product of the end elements each sublist is only computed once

```
C = []
for sublist in A:
    end_product = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, sublist[3:])
    C.append([item*end_product for item in sublist[:3]])
print(C)
```

In the end this gives

```
A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
B = [[1, 2, 3, 20], [6, 7, 8, 990]]
C = [[20, 40, 60], [5940, 6930, 7920]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Stealing the other answer's data:

```
>>> from math import prod
>>> A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
>>> for a in A:
        a[3:] = prod(a[3:]),

>>> A
[[1, 2, 3, 20], [6, 7, 8, 990]]
```

And with our without the above step:

```
>>> [[x * m for x in a[:3]] for a in A for m in [prod(a[3:])]]
[[20, 40, 60], [5940, 6930, 7920]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can do it using a list comprehension and numpy:

```
from numpy import product

index = 5
A = [[5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2], [2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7], [2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 5, 3, 2]]

result = [[b for i, b in enumerate(B) if i < index] + [product(B[index:])] for B in A]

print(result) # [[5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4], [2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 140], [2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 30]]
```

and for your second question:

```
result2 = [[r * R[-1] for r in R[:-1]] for R in result]
print(result2) # [[20, 20, 8, 12, 16], [280, 560, 280, 420, 280], [60, 90, 150, 180, 90]]
```